# Postgres driver doesn't find table in go

Tags: database, postgresql, go

Really strange yet very common error. Relation "users" does not exist. I know what you are saying - that's been asked before!  And it has, but work with me because I'm doing a bunch of checks and it still doesn't go through.

First, this is the migration:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id                  serial PRIMARY KEY,
    obfuscated_id       VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email               VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    encrypted_password  VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    created_at          TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at          TIMESTAMP,
    active              BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE
);
```

And this is the command I'm using to run that migration:

`migrate -path ./migrations -database postgres://myname:password@localhost:5432/five_three_one_development?sslmode=disable up`

I've manually tested that the db exists:

psql

```
\c five_three_one_development
\dt 
 Schema |       Name        | Type  |  Owner
--------+-------------------+-------+----------
 public | schema_migrations | table | myname
 public | users             | table | myname
```

I've manually altered the password on the table using `/password` and set it to password.

Here are the environment variables:

```
DB_NAME=five_three_one_development
DB_PASS=password
DB_USER=myname
```

And when I log those variables I get the same values back:

```
fmt.Printf("NAME:" + os.Getenv("DB_NAME"))
fmt.Printf("USER:" + os.Getenv("DB_USER"))
fmt.Printf("DB_PASS:" + os.Getenv("DB_PASS"))
```

I also perform an environment test at the top of my development server to check that the db is reachable.

```
func (c *ApplicationContext) PerformEnvChecks() {
    err := c.Database.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Database environment check failed: %s", err)
    }

    r, err := c.Database.Exec("SELECT * FROM users")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) // --> pq: relation "users" does not exist
    }

    fmt.Printf("Tables: %v", r)
}
```

And then it fails on the `c.Database.Exec("SELECT * FROM users")` line which means that it's connected to the right database but it cannot find the table.

Out of ideas on this one - thoughts?

**Edit**

Feature request idea for postgresql folks: `\connection_string` -> returns the postgresql connection string given the current user inside of the database connected to.

Comment: Why aren't you printing the _actual_ error message.  You're currently just _assuming_ that an error means the table couldn't be found, when it could be a number of things.  For example, if nothing is _in_ the table, you'll get back a sql.ErrNoRows.

Comment: Good call. Edited. Actual error is `pq: relation "users" does not exist`

Comment: Hmm, I'm at a loss.  It's _likely_ something in how your database is set up or how you're connecting to it (your actual connection code isn't included), but I'm not sure.

Comment: My advise - ALWAYS use full table name with schema name. Otherwise you cannot be sure in which schema is table really created. If you create table directly in psql or other PG gui it will place table into first schema listed in "search_path". But by my experiences GO libraries do not care about "search_path" variable - this is most probably the reason for this error.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the full table name with schema name?  Like inside of the query?

Comment: @user3162553 `public.users` instead of just `users` is what JosMac suggests, I guess.

Comment: Ah same error with: `r, err := c.Database.Exec("SELECT * FROM public.users;")`.  Only have this problem with this go sql driver.  I've never had it with connecting in another language - node or ruby.  Weird.

Comment: @user3162553 Are you certain that your `Database` instance is connected to `five_three_one_development`?

Comment: Are you specifying the port in your database connection code?

Comment: @user3162553 `var name string`; `Database.QueryRow("SELECT current_database()").Scan(&name)`; `fmt.Println(name)` do you get `five_three_one_development`?

Comment: @sindhu_sp I am not specifying my port because it is using the default postgres port.

Comment: @mkopriva I will try that - that sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @mkopriva well damn - it is a different database!  It's connecting to my username as a database so 'myname'.

Comment: Sadly, I still have no idea why.  Is this really the best tool for this?  Seems like building a string isn't the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Golang sql driver isn't clear about the order it expects.  Ditch it. Save the whole connection string into a DATABASE URL variable and use that. Annoying but it seems to have solved the problem.

Pass this as a connection string: `postgres://myname:password@localhost:5432/five_three_one_development?sslmode=disable` and forget trying to build it up.

Comment: Why are you setting those environment variables? `pq` doesn't say that it pays attention to them, it just says it uses the same environment variables as the standard `libpq` and the [`libpq` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) don't mention them either. Or are you setting those and then trying to build a connection string yourself?

Comment: Trying to build the connection string myself.  Database connection will be different depending upon the platform.

Comment: And what code were you using to build the connection string and what connection string was it really building?